# using variable inside other function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables

I have this:

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

and I want to put that in this:

```
$footer_thumbs = get_posts('category_name=HERE&numberposts=9');
```

on the HERE place

how can i do that? please help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$title = the_title();

$footer_thumbs = get_posts('category_name=$title&numberposts=9');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try;

```
$footer_thumbs = get_posts('category_name=' . the_title() . '&numberposts=9');
```

Answer (score -1):

the_title()  works for the posts title.  you need to get the category id or it's slug and pass it in arguments.... but you need to fetch category slug first.